# still not call with ajax in separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in jquery and ajax but my requirement is calling servlet/jsp through ajax using jquery so that my ajax code dosen't work in separate javascript file

Here is my javascript file that I called ajax through jquery :

```
function insertData(idvalue)
{
var forsplit = idvalue.id.split("_");
var qtsrl = forsplit[2];
var qtno = forsplit[3];
alert(qtsrl);
alert(qtno);
var queryid=idvalue.id;
var qtsrl_id = document.getElementById("qstn_srl_"+qtsrl+"_"+qtno).value;
var qstn_no_id = document.getElementById("qstn_no_"+qtsrl+"_"+qtno).value;
alert(qtsrl_id);
alert(qstn_no_id);


$.ajax(
{
    url: "aftermarksave.jsp",
    type: "get",
    data:{setvalues : queryid},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) 
        {   
            alert('Successful :'+data); 

        },
    error: function(data) 
        {
            alert('Not Successful: '+data);
        }   
});

}
```

Still not call to jsp page and I tried for Servlet page also that servlet is not called through ajax.

Comment: Are you calling the insertData function? Check the console for errors and the network tab to make sure all files are downloaded.

Comment: no console errors...alerts displayed successfully

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "URL",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: {setvalues : queryid},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },

                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert('Failed');
                    alert(x.responseText);
                    alert(x.status);
                }
            });
```

OR

```
 $.get("URL",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```